# AWS Load Balancing a Node.js App on port 3000

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I've got a Node.js Express web app that is using the default port 3000 and responds fine on an Ubuntu EC2 instance by elastic ip. I'm trying to setup Load Balancing built into AWS and can't seem to get a good health check to pass

Setup 2 ubuntu servers that server the app fine on port 3000.

Set the load balancer listeners for port 80 to route to Instance port 3000 and also tried routing 3000 to 3000.

Added the amazon-elb/amazon-elb-sg security group to my instance security groups just in case.

Set the health check to port 80 and 3000 to many valid urls within the project.

Anything I'm missing here?

UPDATE:

Turns out it was the simplest thing I was overlooking. Somehow my actual instances were in a security group with only 80 opened and I just had to add a rule to open 3000. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Can you specify your health check configuration?

Comment: It's just through the aws management console. setting it to port 3000 or 80 and /ping for the url. which is a valid url in the express app.

Comment: So what is the full health check configuration?  Have you tried TCP ping for health check rather than HTTP?  Have you verified your /ping URL returns a 200 code? Have you removed your elastic IP?

Comment: I have tried TCP ping instead of HTTP. I have also verified the /ping url returns a 200. I have set the health check to 80 and let apache return the default wich let the health check pass, but when I hit the load balancing url on anything other than 80 I get nothing. Is it maybe my Listeners not setup correctly?

Comment: should I be using nginx, haproxy or apache mod_proxy, or should this just work on 3000 with the listeners pointing 80 to 3000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the load balancer set up only to forward incoming requests on port 80 to port 3000 on the backend instances, then you shouldn't get any response when trying ports other than 80.  If you are making the requests against port 3000 (i.e. http://yourdomain.com:3000/uri) you need to have your load balancer also forward incoming requests on port 3000 to port 3000 on the instances.

If you are using only port 3000 on the instances, then you need to make sure your health check points to port 3000. (i.e. TCP ping 3000, or  HTTP to port 3000 against your `/ping` service).

Comment: can you please let me know what rules should I write in application load balancer to make it work with domain like this - https://www.yourdomain.com:3000/api

Comment: @SachinVairagi You can attach another listener to the NLB that listens on port 3000