# EB with docker multi-container and Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im using Elastic Beanstalk with Docker Multi-Container.

My configuration (in Elastic Beanstalk) is:

- Classic load balance, with listener on port 80 and 3000;
- Security Group with port 80 and 3000 is opened;

The file 'Dockerrun.aws.json' is:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "mynodeapp",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/mynodeapp"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "mynodeapp",
      "image": "node:8.11.3",
      "memoryReservation": 128,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "/usr/src/app/run.sh"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "mynodeapp",
          "containerPath": "/usr/src/app"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Im trying to use the port 3000, but Im receiving timeout error.

I don't know if I need fix something in the aws structure or in my 'dockerrun' file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are:

- My listener (on Load Balance) was setup with http protocol (to port 3000). The correct is TCP protocol;
- The other problem is about the health check ([AWS Load Balancing a Node.js App on port 3000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593798/aws-load-balancing-a-node-js-app-on-port-3000)).